# Error while installing the ionic framework

Tags: frameworks, ionic-framework

I want to install the ionic framework on my windows 8 laptop but it is showing the following warning when i am trying to use the command
npm install -g cordova 
I am already installed
1.Nodejs
2.Git-scm

Please Help me to install the ionic framework

Comment: You need to run this command - npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 0):

1. Install all necessary dependencies. http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html
2. Download and Install node.js
3. Install Cordova using the command: npm install -g cordova
4. Finally install Ionic Framework using the command: npm install -g ionic